# VB.net ClickOnce un-installation modification?

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

During the Click Once uninstallation process, is it possible to add your own instructions for what should be performed along side the automatic process?

I want to add some folder clearing/reg key deletions etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an uninstaller for clickonce applications by [christianlang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463697/christian-lang) called [Wunder.ClickOnceUninstaller](https://github.com/6wunderkinder/Wunder.ClickOnceUninstaller). You can implement it in .net such as(from the repository, code in c#)

```
var uninstallInfo = UninstallInfo.Find("Application Name");
if (uninstallInfo != null)
{
    var uninstaller = new Uninstaller();
    uninstaller.Uninstall(uninstallInfo);
}
```

You can then add additional instructions just before calling the uninstallation function.